# Ngnix SSL truststore/ca cert specification

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a web app on Weblogic server which accepts connection over HTTPS with self signed certificate. Web App on Weblogic server URL https://server1.com:7122/webapp1/

I also have ngnix installed on the same server with a verisign certificate which acts as a frontend to all web apps on the server. Nginx server URL https://server1.com:443/

I want users to access webapp on Weblogic to be accessed via nginx as port 7122 is blocked to access from outside. I added the following rule

```
    location /webapp1 {
        proxy_pass https://server1.com:7122;
    }
```

I am able to access all other apps over Nginx however for webapp1 I get the following error

```
[error] 6680#10132: *147 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.62.144.39, server: server1.com .....
```

Answer (score 6):

On the nginx server, check whether you get any error with this.

```
openssl s_client -connect server1.com:7122;
```

If it works, try proxy_pass without https

```
proxy_pass http://server1.com:7122;
```

Since the Weblogic server is only accessible internally, is it necessary to SSL it, because this adds additional SSL overhead having to encrypt & decrypt 2 times.